# Gitlab nginx problems - nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: linux, nginx, gitlab

I allready have got nginx on own server and theit config allready bind address. I dotn't want to change 80 port, beacause my server have got websites and users on it.

Gitlab in logs have got errors, that

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

what i must to do? Where and how I can change gitlab nginx config?

Comment: Are you using the omnibus package?

Comment: Bind gitlab to another port and configure nginx to proxy to that port

Answer (score 2):

You can run two server on the same port using nginx:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/242679/how-to-run-multiple-nginx-instances-on-different-port

If you installed gitlab-omnibus and if you want to change the default port:

1. Open /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
2. Add **external_url "http:// domain:NewPort"**
3. Run **gitlab-ctl reconfigure**

If you have installed gitlab manually locate nginx's folder (you can type **whereis nginx** on the console) and modify gitlab's file on the **sites-available** subfolder. Normally the file you have to modify is: **/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab**

Answer (score -1):

as u say， u have 2 ng-instances, so u can't listen the same port using different process at the same time.

here is the choice:

1. gitlab-ng listen another port, external-ng listen 80 and proxy_pass the gitlab-ng.
2. stop using external-ng, move ur config of the external-ng to gitlab-ng, using 80/443 port and different domain in gitlab-ng.